# Download blob (text file) from Azure storage to memory as UTF8?

Tags: java, azure, utf-8, blob

I'm downloading a textfile from my blob storage, and I'd like to preserve the contents of the file (encoding and such).

Is there a difference between `downloadText()` and `downloadText("UTF-8",null,null,null)` ? Or is there a better way?

Some test code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(Blob.storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("myblob");

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("mydir/myfile.txt");

        String txt1 = blob.downloadText();
        String txt2 = blob.downloadText("UTF-8", null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences from downloadText function with parameters or no parameters are using the default platform encoding or using the specified encoding, you can refer to the javadoc of Class CloudBlockBlob http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/.

[image]

Per my experience, you can download the text content blob and convert into a UTF8 string, as the below code.

```
InputStream input =  blob.openInputStream();
InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
String utf8str = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(inr);
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. The charset is used to convert the text file into byte array (what a blob at the end is). Therefore you should apply the same encoding that has been used to upload the text file to the blob in order to preserve the original context of your file. When you call downloadText() with no parameters, java tries to use the default characters encoding which is defined in system file.encoding property. This could however lead to an undesired result.

Comment: Ok so then it's safest to use downloadText("UTF-8", null, null, null); Or download as byte array ?

Comment: What downloadText("UTF-8", null, null, null) at the end will do is download as a byte array and convert it to string using UTF-8. So if you have used UTF-8 to upload the text into the blob storage, YES it will be the safest method. If for example uploadText(String content) has been used for upload then you should use downloadText() with no parameters.